# Is it possible to get a songs canvas with the Spotify API?

Tags: spotify

I am trying to find a way to get the url for a tracks canvas, is this possible with the current api? If not, are there any other working solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Hey I know it might be a little late now, but I found this github repositoryhttps://github.com/bartleyg/my-spotify-canvas/blob/master/api/canvases.js that uses Svelte to get the tracks' Canvases. Basically what it does is:

1. gets a track by id
2. makes a post request to the following url: "https://spclient.wg.spotify.com/canvaz-cache/v0/canvases"
3. response is processed
   I honestly did not take the time to see how the response is handled, but can take a look at it in the repository under api/_canvas_pb.js

Hope it was helpful! :)